# Does LWP::UserAgent do any caching

Tags: perl, lwp, lwp-useragent

I'm trying to write a monitoring script in Perl which should check a list of URLs. I am using the [`LWP::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP%3a%3aUserAgent), [`HTTP::Response`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTTP%3a%3aResponse) and [`Time::HiRes`](https://metacpan.org/module/Time%3a%3aHiRes) modules.

Here is a my code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Response;
use Time::HiRes qw( gettimeofday );

while (1) {

    my $start = gettimeofday();

    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
    $ua->agent('lb-healthcheck.pl/0.1');
    $ua->timeout(10);

    # download the tile locally
    my $response = $ua->get("myurl");
    my $content  = $response->content;

    my $end = gettimeofday();

    print "$start - $end = ".(($end-$start)*1000)."\n";
}
```

Running the script manually without the while loop in place I get on average about 70ms response time, but With the while loop in place I get about 5ms response time which is unreal.

Does `LWP::UserAgent` do any caching? If yes is it possible to disable it and how? If not what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you're doing benchmarks with LWP, then make sure to disregard the timings of the first request. While doing the first request, LWP dynamically loads about two dozens of perl modules (in some situations, e.g. if requesting a https URL, even more) --- something which does not happen on the 2nd and following requests. You can see all these dynamically loaded modules by looking into with `strace` into the script invocation.

Answer (score 1):

`LWP` doesn't do any caching of its own unless you tell it to, but there is a lot between LWP and the host site. Are you working through a proxy, for example? If so then it will be caching pages it fetches in case they are required a second time. There are also many other caches in the cloud that may be speeding up your response, but a time of 7ms implies a reasonably local cache.

You should also be using the `tv_interval` subroutine from `Time::HiRes` to calculate the intervals. It expects you to store the result-pairs from `gettimeofday` in arrays, and will calculate the difference between two of these pairs. You code would look like this

```
use Time::HiRes qw( gettimeofday  tv_interval );

while () {

    my $start = [ gettimeofday() ];

    # download the tile locally

    my $end = [ gettimeofday() ];

    print tv_interval($start, $end), "\n";
}
```

For what it's worth, for an ordinary national web site I get around 500ms for the initial fetch, followed by roughly 300ms for subsequent fetches. So some caching is going on, but with far less impact than you are reporting.

Comment: Thanks for advice on using tv_interval. I'm not using is to calculate the interval.

I'm issuing http requests to localhost so no proxy is involved. I imagine caching occurs on the server side that's why I'm getting such differences in the intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `conn_cache` with a [LWP::ConnCache](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.04/lib/LWP/ConnCache.pm) object that is set to drop all connections (see its `total_capacity` subroutine for e.g)

Comment: Have tried this to no avail. Seems that caching is done on the server side rather on my LWP::UserAgent side.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that your're not estimating the elapsed time correctly. gettimeof day returns an array containing both: seconds and microseconds elapsed, so in order to calculate the time elapsed you should need to do some conversions. Something like:

```
my ($init_sec, $init_usec) = gettimeofday
# SOME CODE HERE
my ($stop_sec, $stop_usec) = gettimeofday

if ( $init_usec > $stop_usec ) {
   $stop_usec += 1_000_000;
   $stop_sec--;
}

#convert seconds into mseconds
my $tsec  = ( $stop_sec  - $init_sec ) * 1_000; 

# convert usecs into msecs
my $tusec = ( $stop_usec - $init_usec) / 1_000;

# elapsed time is $tsec + $tusec
```

Comment: I'm always preferred `Time::HiRes::time`, no need for contortions, it's just time since epoch as a foat.

Comment: There are times when more resolution is needed than the one provided by Time::HiRes::time

Comment: Yes, I do need the microseconds accuracy, gettimeofday is not the problem here as when I run the code without the while loop I get the elapsed time I'm expexting.

Answer (score 0):

LWP doesn't do caching, but the OS will probably cache data like the result of the DNS lookups, so those will only take time on the first lookup and after the OS cache expires.